# how to check timestamp of the high value for the table partitions in oracle sql

Tags: sql, timezone, database-partitioning, timezone-offset, sql-timestamp

the high value for one of my table partition in oracle sql is `TIMESTAMP' 2022-09-06 00:00:00'`. My understanding is that it does not represent any timezone. Is there a way for me to check what timezone is it referring to? Thanks.